# How do I package a distribution on Drupal.org?

Tags: 8, community-official-site, distributions

I am getting some old and mixed documentation issues with building a release for a Drupal 8-based distribution Drupal.org.

The main documentation is [How to package a distribution on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/packaging-a-distribution/how-to-package-a-distribution-on-drupalorg), which says to use `drush make` to create a drupal-org.make file. However, when I try to run this command on my site, I get the following error message.

> Make has been removed, in favor of Composer. Use the make-convert command in Drush 8 to quickly upgrade your build to Composer.

That's fine, since I am already using Composer for the project! But how do I actually then publish these dependencies on Drupal.org? Drupal.org is definitely not reading the composer.json file, and building the zip files.

Do I just have to manually make a git tag which includes all the files in the *vendoré directory, so that Drupal.org knows to build this?

I am running Drush version 9.5.2.

Comment: When you see the top three D8 distributions (commerce, lightning, open social) they all use composer scaffolds, for example https://github.com/goalgorilla/social_template

Comment: As long as you commit a *drupal-org.make* file together the distribution files, on drupal.org, you don't need to execute any command, locally.

Comment: @4k4 That is on Github. On Drupal.org, the software that creates the packages for every project doesn't still support a composer.json file for distributions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I see, although you can build now D8 distributions with composer alone as the commerce kickstart project does or you can make a dual approach like the other two distributions.

Comment: @4k4 As long as the distribution repository has a drupal-org.make file describing the dependencies, every method would work, even using Composer, if there is a script that is able to write the dependencies on that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Drupal.org, there isn't yet support for a distribution composer.json file, as reported on [Support for distributions](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_composer/issues/2715441).

The package system used from Drupal.org, to be able to build the package files for a distribution, requires just two files: drupal-org.make and drupal-org-core.make. The latter is only necessary when using a Drupal release that is not official.

If your system doesn't allow you to create a .make file as required from Drupal.org, you can manually create it with any text editor, as long as you use the correct file format (see [Example drupal.org make file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/packaging-a-distribution/example-drupalorg-make-file)), and you follow what reported in [Drupal.org distribution packaging requirements](https://www.drupal.org/node/1475972). In particular, see the notes reported at the beginning.

- External libraries are validated against a whitelist of GPL-compatible libraries since all code distributed from Drupal.org must be GPL compatible
- Git clones from Drupal.org sandboxes (as opposed to full projects) are not supported
- Patches hosted on servers other than Drupal.org are not supported
- Modules and themes hosted on servers other than Drupal.org are not supported
- If you need to specify anything other than an official release of the Drupal core project itself, that needs to go into a separate drupal-org-core.make file
- If you request a specific Git revision you must also define the branch that revision came from

In future, some of those restrictions could be lift. There are feature requests / bugs opened in the [packages.drupal.org issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/project_composer).